# Quais tags posso usar para documentar o meu código?

Tags: java, documentação, javadoc

Estou buscando melhores formas de documentar o meu código no Netbeans.

Além das [*tags* conhecidas e utilizadas](http://www.devmedia.com.br/javadoc-implementando-documentacao-atraves-do-netbeans/2495) no Javadoc algo me chamou a atenção e despertou minha curiosidade.

Ao digitar `{@` surgem algumas sugestões de documentação com *tags* que nunca vi e que não sei para que serve. Algumas:

```
{@code}
{@docRoot}
{@link}
{@linkplain}
{@literal}
```

`{@link}` seria uma substituição da tag `@link`? Para que servem essas outras tags?

Comment: Você pode consultar a relação completa bem como a explicação do significado de cada uma diretamente no [site oficial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#javadoctags).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Você pode obter uma [lista das principais *tags* do Javadoc na Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc#Overview_of_Javadoc) ou pode obter na [documentação oficial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html).

| Tag | Descrição | Onde usar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| @author | Designer o autor do código | Class, Interface, Enum |
| @version | Especifica a versão do software | Class, Interface, Enum |
| @since | Data inicial da funcionalidade | Class, Interface, Enum Field, Method |
| @see | Link para outra parte da documentação | Class, Interface, Enum Field, Method |
| @param | Descreve um parâmetro de um método | Method |
| @return | Descreve o retorna de um método | Method |
| @exception | Descreve uma exceção ser lançada | Method |
| @throws | O mesma que o anterior * | Method |
| @deprecated | Indica que o método está obsoleta | Method |
| {@inheritDoc} | Copia a descrição do método pai | Overriding Method |
| {@link reference} | Estabelece um link para algum recurso | Class, Interface, Enum Field, Method |
| {@value #STATIC FIELD} | Descreve um campa estática | Static Field |

`*` Normalmente a *tag* `throws` é preferida quando o método uma uma [*checked exception*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Checked_exceptions).

Estas são as recomendações. Obviamente você pode usar como quiser. Muitas pessoas não gostam de usar determinadas *tags* que não acrescentam informação relevante para a documentação. Autor é a mais óbvia delas. Controle de autoria e data de criação deveria ser controlado por um software de controle de versão. Mas depende da cultura de cada equipe.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Mais ou menos, não é desatualização, é escolha das mais usadas. Por isto linkei a documentação oficial também.